# I am getting Terminal error on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, powershell, compiler-errors

I have just started learning C++ and I am getting this terminal error. I tried every possible way on the internet and uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code 3 times, but nothing is working. This is the error I get:

[image: This is the error I get]

The code is running if I try to run it through command prompt. This is the code:

[image: This is the code.]

Comment: Don't attach images, copy paste the code here instead.

Comment: Remember that executable files in Windows ends with a `.exe` suffix.

Comment: D-RAJ just a for loop bro, nothing fancy

Comment: Some programmer dude, Bro, how can that help me, the code is giving error even in hello world. I guess there is some window power shell error.

Comment: It's not the building of the code that gives you an error, it's the ***running*** of the built program. PowerShell believes you try to execute a file of type `0_Loops`, and of course there's no program to handle that kind of file.

Comment: @DirghayuJoshi Did you compile the source file before calling it as an executable?

Comment: @DirghayuJoshi Try running `ls` (or `Get-ChildItem`) inside the terminal - which files does it show?

Comment: I suggest you separate the building and running into two distinct steps, so it's easier to distinguish between them and the errors possible from each one of them.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried running Get-ChildItem in compiler, it is giving history of programs I tried to run

Comment: Alright, so we know the compilation succeeds. It's just PowerShell that won't recognize them as executables. Change the executable name from `5.0_Loops` to `5.0_Loops.exe` instead, and it'll probably work - just like @Someprogrammerdude already suggested

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much bro, I didn't get u that time.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Bro, whenever I am running some code, my compiler is not making .exe file, if I press the Run button for 5.0_Loops.cpp it makes 5.0_Loops not 5.0_Loops.exe

Comment: And @MathiasR.Jessen thank you very much for your time, can't thank u enough

Comment: @D-RAJ Bro, first of all, thanks for ur time. The problem which I figured out now is, when I run a code as simple as hello world, with the file name "Hello_world.cpp" it compile it and make it "Hello_world" instead of "Hello_world.exe". What can I do to change it??

Comment: Visual Studio Code have configuration files you can edit to build and run. In them you can set the exact flags you need, including generating custom output file-names that correctly end with the `.exe` suffix. If you're using MinGW to build then see e.g. [this Microsoft tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) for how to configure VS Code with MinGW.

Comment: "my compiler is not making .exe file" - that's because you're not asking it to. `g++ 5.0_Loops.cpp -o 5.0_Loops.exe`